# Most efficient way to check for special characters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

What's the most efficient way to check if a JavaScript string has special characters? I am trying to use a loop and checking various characters, but that does not seem very efficient, nor does it catch all characters.

Specifically, the goal is to check if a string contains any characters except A-Z, and 0-9, excluding Q and R.

Comment: you labelled this regex, where is your code?

Comment: What have you tried? If you've done any research at all, you should at least have some attempt that isn't quite working right. Show that and ask why it isn't working (ideally saying why you think it should).

Comment: I tried looping though and checking character by character...that is not very efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into using a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and the [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method.

**[`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)**:

> Executes the search for a match between a regular expression and a
>   specified string. Returns true or false.

[`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) may also be helpful, but it's not a standard.

[Regular Expression Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/)

Comment: do I have to import RegExp or something? It's telling me that it is not being found

Comment: Can you show me how you're using it, please? Also, RegExp seems to not be a standard, however, you don't need it for this issue anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a `myString` contains any characters except `A-Z`, and `0-9`, excluding `Q` and `R`, go with

```
var re = /[^A-PS-Z0-9]+/i;
document.write(re.test(myString));
```

where `i` at the end of `re` pattern is optional, depends on if you want regex pattern case insensitive or not.

Check **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RvjeD/)**.